# Is this equation solvable for a given $a$ and $n$?

Tags: calculus

$n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to find the value of $x$ where:

$$a = \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{n+1-i}$$

In case it helps in some way, $x = \frac{1+\alpha}{(1+r)(1 + \gamma)}$ where $\alpha \text{ and } r$ are known and the real incognita is $\gamma$. I've tried considering the geometric sum, but I ended up with

$$\frac{x(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x}=a$$

Comment: Not that it helps but you also have $a = x\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}x^j$

Answer (score 2):

Even when $n=2$, this amounts to writing down the solution to $x^3+x^2+x-a=0$, which can involve tricky nested radicals.

When $n=4$, we would need to solve $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x-a=0$, which for generic $a$ is impossible to solve at all, by Galois-theoretic considerations.

So this task looks algebraically impossible in general.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{n-i+1}=x\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{n-i}=x\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{i}=x\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^{n+2}-x}{x-1}.
$$

Let
$$
g(x)\equiv\frac{x^{n+2}-x}{x-1}.
$$
Note that $g$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=1$, so let's just define
$$
f(x)\equiv\begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{if }x\neq1\\
n+1 & \text{if }x=1
\end{cases}
$$
to avoid that issue (you can check that the original sum and $f$ agree at $x=1$).

We are looking for $x$ such that $f(x) = a$.
By the above, if $a=n+1$, then $x=1$ satisfies this requirement.
Otherwise, some simple algebra shows that $x$ must satisfy
$$
x^{n+2}-\left(a+1\right)x+a=0.
$$
The left hand side is a polynomial.
For low orders (e.g., $n+2\leq4$), you can find the zeroes of the polynomial analytically.
Otherwise, you can use a [root-finding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) (e.g., [Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)).

For higher order polynomials, this approach is probably faster than applying a root finding method to $a - \sum_{i=0}^n x^{n-i+1}$ as each iteration in this alternate approach will require lots of [floating point operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS).

Note that a solution may not exist in the reals. For example, if $n=1$ and $a=-1$, the only solutions are complex.